# Error creating user registry object. The exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dummy.registry.CustomRegistry (initialization failure)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7

Hi I currently have an WAS 7.0.29 and we've planned to update it to fix pack 41.

Upon the installation of the Fix pack I have encountered this:

```
[11/10/16 19:32:24:505 SGT] 00000000 UserRegistryC E   SECJ0281E: Error creating user registry object. The exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dummy.registry.CustomRegistry (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:139)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:294)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.initialize(UserRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.do_createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getUserRegistryImpl(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getString(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:850)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getPrincipalName(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:577)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.CSIv2ConfigImpl.initializeOnServer(CSIv2ConfigImpl.java:723)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.CSIv2ConfigImpl.initialize(CSIv2ConfigImpl.java:1151)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.CSIv2ConfigImpl.<init>(CSIv2ConfigImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityConfigObjectFactoryImpl.createCSIv2Config(SecurityConfigObjectFactoryImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator.do_getCSIv2Config(SecurityObjectLocator.java:852)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.RasHelper.printStackTrace(RasHelper.java:368)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.RasHelper.throwableToString(RasHelper.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.MessageEvent6.convertParameters(MessageEvent6.java:346)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.MessageEvent6.<init>(MessageEvent6.java:221)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.Tr.fireMessageEvent(Tr.java:1538)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.Tr.error(Tr.java:733)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.do_createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:696)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getUserRegistryImpl(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getString(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:850)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getPrincipalName(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:577)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.CSIv2ConfigImpl.initializeOnServer(CSIv2ConfigImpl.java:723)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.CSIv2ConfigImpl.initialize(CSIv2ConfigImpl.java:1151)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.CSIv2ConfigImpl.<init>(CSIv2ConfigImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityConfigObjectFactoryImpl.createCSIv2Config(SecurityConfigObjectFactoryImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator.do_getCSIv2Config(SecurityObjectLocator.java:852)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator.getCSIv2Config(SecurityObjectLocator.java:882)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator.getCSIv2Config(SecurityObjectLocator.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getProperty(ContextManagerImpl.java:2102)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getProperty(ContextManagerImpl.java:2141)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException.printStackTrace(WSSecurityException.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.IncidentReportHeader.writeTo(IncidentReportHeader.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentLogger.writeHeader(IncidentLogger.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentLogger.writeIncidentTo(IncidentLogger.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.logIncident(FfdcProvider.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.logIncident(FfdcProvider.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:148)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentEntry.log(IncidentEntry.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.Ffdc.log(Ffdc.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter.processException(FFDCFilter.java:114)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.do_createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:694)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getUserRegistryImpl(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.distSecurityComponentImpl.getRealmFromUserRegistry(distSecurityComponentImpl.java:2808)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.distSecurityComponentImpl.initialize(distSecurityComponentImpl.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityComponentImpl.initialize(SecurityComponentImpl.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1191)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1098)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponents(ContainerHelper.java:900)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:750)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:666)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:213)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:341)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:221)
    at com.ibm.websphere.ras.Manager.createRASTraceLogger(Manager.java:241)
    at com.dummy.registry.CustomRegistry.<clinit>(CustomRegistry.java:126)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:199)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:294)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.initialize(UserRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.do_createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:686)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission com.ibm.ws.ffdc.SupportORBFFDC read)
    at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:121)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:194)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1293)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:404)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:388)
    at com.ibm.websphere.ras.WsJrasTraceLogger.<clinit>(WsJrasTraceLogger.java:98)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:199)
    ... 43 more
.
```

My guess is that the issue is in the CustomRegistry that we have made which looks like this:

```
public class CustomRegistry implements UserRegistry {

    protected static RASTraceLogger traceLogger;

    private static RASMessageLogger msgLogger;

    static {
        Manager mgr = Manager.getManager();

        traceLogger = mgr.createRASTraceLogger("MyWebsite", "Authentication", "Registry", CustomRegistry.class.getName());

        msgLogger = mgr.createRASMessageLogger("MyWebsite", "Authentication", "Registry", CustomRegistry.class.getName());
        msgLogger.setMessageFile("com.dummy.registry.RegistryMessages");
    }
```

It points the usage of mgr.createRASTraceLogger in the CustomRegistry but I'm not sure what is the right approach for it.

Right now, I can't even start my server.

Your suggestions will be a great help! :)

Comment: Do you have Java 2 security enabled? Maybe try to disable it in the `security.xml` setting `enforceJava2Security="false"`

Comment: Hi sir thanks for your response, it is already set to "false" but the problem is still there.

Comment: Maybe you installed fixpack as different user? Try to start server as administrator user.

Comment: The error clearly indicates that Java 2 security is somehow still enabled.  Perhaps check the generic JVM arguments?  Perhaps generate a server start script to see if security is enabled there for some reason?

Comment: Hi sir thanks also for your response! Where can I check if the java 2 security is still enabled? Where can I find the JVM args or the start script?

Comment: I've run it in Administrator and still I get the error.

Comment: See [Setting generic JVM arguments in WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417365).  To check the startup script, use `startServer server1 -script script.sh` (or .bat), and check for `-Djava.security.manager`.  Note that "running it in Administrator" will have no effect: you are getting an error due to Java-level security, not OS-level security.